# How to implement ViewHolder pattern with separator?

Tags: android, android-viewholder

I have a list view that displays two different kinds of data one is a separator. Each data type is stored in one array list. Thus there are two lists. The content of each list is separated from the other one by a special row (separator). The first row is a separator row as well. In `getView` i have to distinguish between normal data rows and separator rows.

```
// returns true if a separator row must be displayed at pos. 
private boolean isSeperator(int pos) {
        return pos == 0 || pos == data.size() + 1;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    if(isSeperator(position)) {
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view_seperator, parent, false);
        TextView seperator = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_list_view_seperator);
        seperator.setText("Seperator");
    }
    else {
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.my_layout, parent, false);

        TextView txtview = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.foo);
        ImageView icon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.bar);

        MyData myData = (MyData) getItem(position);
        txtview.setText(myData.getName());
        icon.setImageBitmap(myData.getIcon());
    }

    return convertView;
}
```

First I check whether a separator has to be displayed on the current position. This works fine.

I tried to implement the view holder pattern, but I constantly fail. Can somebody could please show me how to use this pattern in such a case where different types of rows including separators must be taken into consideration?

Comment: Here's an example from Google ; https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/master/android/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/iosched/ui/SimpleSectionedListAdapter.java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to implement sep**a**rators, I would strongly recommend that you do it using the *viewType* mechanism in the `Adapter`. So, if you have your adapter which already serves one type of `View`, you can override:

```
private final static int TYPE_SEPARATOR = 0;
private final static int TYPE_ITEM = 1;


@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 2;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return isSeparator(position) ? TYPE_SEPARATOR : TYPE_ITEM;
}
```

This way, when your `getView()` gets called, you will have the correct type of `convertView` (which can still also be `null`) and you should be fine with something like:

```
private final LayoutInflater mInflater;

public MyAdapter(Context context) {
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (isSeparator(position)) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_separator, parent, false);
        }

        setupSeparator(convertView);
    } else {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        }

        setupListItem(convertView, position);
    }

    return convertView;
}

private boolean isSeparator(int position) {
    return position == 0 || position == data.size() + 1;    // Is the + 1 needed here?
}
```

Comment: This solution works for me. Furthermore I could improve my orthography skills :P.

Answer (score 1):

Given your condition to determine whether a row is a separator (first or last), it seems like it doesn't need to be part of this list.

Consider using `ListView.addHeader(View view)` and `ListView.addFooter(View view)` instead (these need to be set *before* you do `ListView.setAdapter(ListAdapter listAdapter)`) if you need the separators to scroll with the list.

Comment: Hi, i know these methods and `ListView.addHeader(View view)` would indeed be a good solution. However, the second seperator is located _between_ the content of my two lists and not and must not be placed at the end of list view. Each separator is the title of the following rows.

Comment: You have two ListViews? What do you mean by "two lists"?

Comment: @ataulm he means he mixes data from two sources into this one adapter as far as I can tell.

Comment: exactly, i have data from two sources (two array lists).

Comment: consider creating an adapter which handles the merging of these two lists (and maybe relevant separators) into a single data source. Then you can combine with seb's answer with view types.